# Create dynamic cell with link.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, vine

I'm developing application similar to Vine Application, in that comment cell is giving navigation (@User is there or #tag is there) that is exactly working if user or tag is there otherwise not.

If anyone know, how to do that please give me reference or suggestion (Please don't give any suggestion like if word found with @ or # then give string attribute  that I already done that  but I want exactly vice comment cell )

You can give some idea or suggestion also.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TTTAttributedLabel](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/TTTAttributedLabel/1.7.1/Classes/TTTAttributedLabel.html). It will help you to provide link action.
Implement it as follows

```
TTTAttributedLabel *label = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[label setAttributedText:@"yourText"];
label.delegate = self;
label.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingTypeLink;
[label addLinkToURL:url withRange:range];
[yourCell.contentView addSubview:label];
```

and you can capture the link action in:

```
- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url
```

which is the `TTTAttributedLabelDelegate` method. Don't forget to add `TTTAttributedLabelDelegate` in the interface file.

Comment: thanks for giving answer but i already use that class if have some other idea or other way to accomplish that.

Comment: plz read my question carefully. its working but i want exactly vine comment cell